# Deep Link to App from Facebook app in Windows Phone 8

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8, deep-linking

I have a facebook page that posts information on user's wall.
What I want to do is, when the user is in the Facebook mobile app, and if he clicks on links posted by my facebook page, the app must redirect it to a specific page in my own windows app installed in the phone, rather than taking it to the web browser.

Now, I have registered my app with Facebook for deeplinking and followed everything as specified here:
http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/sso/

I know, we cannot override deep linking for http and https but is there any way through which I can achieve this.

Note: I am able to deep link into the same page with the same uri using another test app but it fails when I try it from the facebook app.

The protocol setup is msft-43245dd584d84cde837aa19a4a2e3914 (I have used my store ID in actual code)

and the uri to navigate is `http://msft-43245dd584d84cde837aa19a4a2e3914?type=xyz&id=123"`

Comment: msft-... is a protocol, so url should look like msft-4..14://blah

Comment: That is fine...but the urls are posted from facebook with https protocol